# Magnetic dipole moment of volume current derivation

Tags: magnetic-fields, electricity, potential, magnetic-moment, dipole-moment

The multipole expansion of the magnetic potential yields the dipole term :
$$\mathbf A_{dipole}(\mathbf{r}) =\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r^{2}}\int (\hat {\mathbf r} \cdot {\mathbf r}') \mathbf J {dV}'$$

How do I get from this expression to the final expression :
$$\mathbf A_{dipole}(\mathbf{r}) =\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r^{2}}\left (\frac{1}{2}\int ( {\mathbf r}'\times \mathbf J) \ {dV}'\right) \times \hat{\mathbf r} $$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following identity, that can be obtained with the BAC-CAB-rule:
$$
(\mathbf{r'} \times \mathbf{J}) \times \mathbf{\hat r} = -\mathbf{\hat r} \times (\mathbf{r'} \times \mathbf{J})=\mathbf{J} (\mathbf{r'} \cdot {\mathbf{\hat r}})
-\mathbf{r'} (\mathbf{\hat r} \cdot \mathbf{J}).
$$
We will show, that the two expressions on the right yield the same integral:
$$
\int dV' (\mathbf{r'} \times \mathbf{J}) \times \mathbf{\hat r} = 
\int dV' [\mathbf{J} (\mathbf{r'} \cdot \mathbf{\hat r})
-\mathbf{r'} (\mathbf{\hat r} \cdot \mathbf{J})]=2\int dV' \mathbf{J} (\mathbf{r'} \cdot \mathbf{\hat r})
$$
(which would give you your second equation)

Proof: First show that the volume integral of the product of the current density with any gradient $\mathbf{\nabla'} f$ is $0$. Note that the multipole expansion assumes that the current density $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})$ is localized  $(r'<<r)$ and considers a magnetostatic szenario (continuity equation yields: $0=\partial_t \rho=-\mathbf{\nabla'}\mathbf{J}$ (1)), for a magnetic field far away from the origin (where $\mathbf{J}$ is localized and the only charges $\rho$ are). Since $\mathbf{J}$ is localized at the origin we can choose a Volume $V$ big enough, such that the integration over the surface $\partial V$ of $\mathbf{J}$ yields $0$ (2):
$$
\int dV' (\mathbf{J}\cdot(\mathbf{\nabla'} f))=\int dV' (\mathbf{\nabla'}\cdot (f\mathbf{J}))-\int dV' f \, (\mathbf{\nabla'}\cdot\mathbf{J})\stackrel{(1)}{=}\int dV' (\mathbf{\nabla'}\cdot(\mathbf{J}f)) \\
\stackrel{Gauß}{=} \int_{\partial V} \mathbf{dA'}\cdot\mathbf{J}f\stackrel{(2)}{=}0
$$
Now choose $f:=r'_i r'_k \Rightarrow \mathbf{\nabla'} f= r'_i \mathbf{\hat r'_k}+r'_k \mathbf{\hat r'_i}$. We get:
$$
0=\int dV' (\mathbf{J}\cdot(r'_i \mathbf{\hat r'_k}+r'_k \mathbf{\hat r'_i}))= \int dV' (r'_i J_k+r'_k J_i). (3)
$$
With this we finally get:
$$
\int dV' (-\mathbf{r'}(\mathbf{\hat r}\cdot\mathbf{J}))_i=\sum_k \int dV' (-r'_i \hat r_k J_k)\stackrel{(3)}{=} \sum_k \int dV' (r'_k \hat r_k J_i)=\int dV' (\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{\hat r}\cdot\mathbf{r'}))_i,
$$
which concludes the proof.  $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \square$

Comment: Actually your first line is incorrect, the triple product we want is $$ ({\mathbf r}'\times \mathbf J)  \times \hat{\mathbf r}$$ and not $$ {\mathbf r}'\times (\mathbf J  \times \hat{\mathbf r}) $$

Comment: I've corrected the missspelling. Thank you! It should be coherent now.

Comment: I'm sorry but your answer is unreadable, first of all the first integral is with the wrong parentheses.. Then you define f as the dot product of 2 scalars?? Is the gradient with respect to prime coordinates or unprime coordinates? at the end your write 2 vectors right next to each other with no multiplier between them.. Please try to make it more readable from the point where you define f, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your review. I'd say one can distinguish a dot product from a normal one simply from the fact that the product is between two vectors or not. But I'll correct it if it makes more easy to understand. What do you mean by wrong parentheses? The Gradient is with respect to the input of $\mathbf{J}$ and $f$ which is prime.

Comment: The parentheses in the first integral line are misplaced, they still represent the wrong cross product.. Please elaborate on the calculation of the gradient of f because I don't understand it. I'm also don't understand what $\mathbf{\hat r_k}$ represents and how it becomes $\mathbf{\hat r'_k}$ later on..

Comment: oh yes I forgot to correct that one. Thank you.

Comment: Notice that I extended my previous comment.

Comment: $\mathbf{\nabla'} f=r'_i(\mathbf{\nabla'}r'_k)+(\mathbf{\nabla'}r'_i) r'_k=r'_i\mathbf{\hat r'_k}+\mathbf{\hat r'_i} r'_k$. $\mathbf{\hat r'_k}$ represents the prime unitvektor for the k'th component: $\mathbf{\hat r'_k}=\sum_{n=1}^3 \delta_{nk} \mathbf{\hat r'_n}$. E.g. $\mathbf{\hat r'_2}=(0,1,0)^T$

Comment: I went over it again and now I understand, Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There is in identity for the triple product:
$$
\mathbf{r}^{'} \times (\mathbf{J} \times \hat{\mathbf{r}}) = 
\mathbf{J} (\mathbf{r}^{'} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{r}})
-\hat{\mathbf{r}} (\mathbf{r}^{'} \cdot \mathbf{J}) 
$$
Substitutring it in the exprerssion, one is left with the integral:
$$
\int dV^{'} \hat{\mathbf{r}} (\mathbf{r}^{'} \cdot \mathbf{J}) 
$$
Which vanishes, as averaging over all directions.

(there would in any dimensionality something like $\int d \theta \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is angle between $J$ and $\mathbf{r}^{'}$).

However, I do not see, from where does the factor $1/2$ arise.

Comment: Why would the integral over the second term vanish? (see my answer below)

Comment: @Rodrigo seems like I've wrongly interpreted $\hat{\mathbf{r}}$. I thought it is independent of  $\mathbf{r}^{'}{$, is it a unit vector in a certain direction?

Comment: It is independand of $\mathbf{r'}$. $\mathbf{r'}=r'\mathbf{\hat r'}$ is what you integrate over and $\mathbf{r}=r\mathbf{\hat r}$ is the input of $\mathbf{A}_{dipole}(\mathbf{r})$.

Comment: @Rodrigo thanks for clarification. But I cannot see still, why the integral mentioned above is nonzero. $\mathbf{J}$ is some fixed vector, and we integrate over the whole space the scalar product of it with $\mathbf{r}^{'}$. And for each choice of $\mathbf{r}^{'}$., there would be the oppositely directed vector, so it seems like they need to cancel.

Comment: We consider the general case where $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{r'})$ is not constant, but dependant on $\mathbf{r'}$. I think if the input was written every time everything would get a bit unclearer, so the questioner and I left it out. But you are correct: The way its written $\mathbf{J}$ seems constant. :)

Comment: @Rodrigo now everything is clear, thanks!